# Appending level of column labels to MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change a single level of column labels within a MultiIndex.

For example,

```
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)))
test.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Level1'],['A','B','C','D'],['Level3']])

Out: 
     Level1                              
          A         B         C         D
     Level3    Level3    Level3    Level3
0  0.153388  0.253070  0.338756  0.025598
1  0.818954  0.169352  0.851079  0.823263
2  0.535703  0.432627  0.690446  0.599997
3  0.304654  0.919936  0.095747  0.404449
```

I would like to change the 'Level 3' labels to ['1','2','3','4'] but cannot find a clean way of doing it.

I have tried the below which gives an iterable of 16 elements so not what I need.

```
test.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Level1'],['A','B','C','D'],['1','2','3','4']])
```

The only workaround I found was defining each level manually at the beginning and redefining the MultiIndex

eg,

```
level1 = ['Level1','Level1','Level1','Level1']
level2 = ['A','B','C','D']
level3 = ['1','2','3','4']
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)),columns=[level1,level2,level3])
```

Is there a neater solution? I am working with large data sets so the above is very cumbersome.

Comment: But there is a semantic difference here, in your initial construction the labels are the same for level 2, so you can't just rename the level as it will again set all columns to the same name at that level, whilst your latter approach defines 4 different label values at that level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need to set the level values and then the labels in 2 steps:

```
In [153]:
test.columns = test.columns.set_levels(['0','1','2','3'],level=2)
test.columns = test.columns.set_labels([0,1,2,3],level=2)
test

Out[153]:
     Level1                              
          A         B         C         D
          0         1         2         3
0  0.122865  0.778640  0.582170  0.695648
1  0.051477  0.479084  0.150539  0.143929
2  0.362087  0.285109  0.465092  0.205157
3  0.963744  0.730001  0.148460  0.474678
```

The reason is because initially your third level all have the same label (0) as the column is repeated:

```
In [155]:
test.columns

Out[155]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['Level1'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['Level3']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

but what you want is to rename the levels and the labels resulting in the following:

```
In [158]:
test.columns

Out[158]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['Level1'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['0', '1', '2', '3']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

So you can either reconstruct the multi-index again as you've tried already or set the level values and then the label values as I've shown above

Comment: Thank you! The detail I missed was that you have to set both levels AND labels.  I assume this is the same if I had started with two levels and wanted to insert a third.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`

```
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)))
index_tuples = [('Level1',letter,number) for letter,number in zip(['A','B','C','D'],range(1,4+1))]
test.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tuples)
```